# C# Expression Tree Simple Arithmetic

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, expression

I've been trying to figure out how to achieve some simple maths using the Expression class.

What I'm trying to do is this

```
(1 + 10 * 15)
```

When I try to do this via Expression.Add and Expression.Constant but the result I get is this

```
((1 + 10) * 15)
```

Which is not right as it evaluates the 1 + 10 first instead of 10 * 15.

Is there a way to combine Expression.Add/Multiply etc.. without it creating the brackets? I assume there is but I just can't find where or how!

The test code I have is this

```
        var v1 = Expression.Constant(1, typeof(int));
        var v2 = Expression.Constant(10, typeof(int));
        var v3 = Expression.Constant(15, typeof(int));

        var a1 = Expression.Add(v1, v2);
        var m2 = Expression.Multiply(a1, v3);
```

Thanks for your time,

Richard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var a1 = Expression.Multiply(v2, v3)
var m2 = Expression.Add(a1, v1)
```

Comment: I tried this before and yeah it did work as expected but because this is part of a bigger picture the order that the parts are parsed from and built is plus first.

So I'm going to have to order the parts in order of BODMAS for the expression to be built correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You have to do your multiplication first:

```
Expression.Add(v1, Expression.Multiply(v2, v3))
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
    var a1 = Expression.Add(v1, v2);
    var m2 = Expression.Multiply(a1, v3);
```

try with this

```
    var a1 = Expression.Multiply(v2, v3);
    var m2 = Expression.Add(v1, a1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you find a bigger example:
http://teusje.wordpress.com/2011/08/07/c-expression-trees/
It uses parameters, constants and binaryexpressions.